# Compiling C++ without the delete operator

Tags: c++, linker, delete-operator

I am writing a C++ program for an embedded device, and I want to compile it without libstdc++, exceptions, and dynamic memory allocation.

Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
    virtual void Foo() override{}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

Immediately I ran into the following errors.

> $ gcc src.cpp -static -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=c++11
>
> /tmp/ccd0Wydq.o: In function `A::~A()':
>   src.cpp:(.text._ZN1AD2Ev[_ZN1AD5Ev]+0x29): undefined reference to`
>   operator delete(void*)' /tmp/ccd0Wydq.o: In function `A::~A()':
>   src.cpp:(.text._ZN1AD0Ev[_ZN1AD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to`
>   operator delete(void*)' /tmp/ccd0Wydq.o: In function `B::~B()':
>   src.cpp:(.text._ZN1BD2Ev[_ZN1BD5Ev]+0x35): undefined reference to`
>   operator delete(void*)' /tmp/ccd0Wydq.o: In function `B::~B()':
>   src.cpp:(.text._ZN1BD0Ev[_ZN1BD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to`
>   operator delete(void*)'
>   /tmp/ccd0Wydq.o:(.rodata._ZTV1A[_ZTV1A]+0x20): undefined reference to
>   `__cxa_pure_virtual' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 1

I understand why `__cxa_pure_virtual` is needed, but couldn't for the life of me get why I need a `delete` implementation.

I perform no `new` or `delete` operations in the code, why would it be needed?

When implementing both functions to satisfy the linker's demands, it seems that neither are called (as expected).

Is there a way to avoid implementing these functions?

Comment: Is there something wrong with implementing them by having them do nothing?

Comment: I would stub them by a big `assert(1==0)` to be sure that they are not called.

Comment: It's an ugly solution. I'll do it if it's the only solution, but I want to know why it's the case.

Comment: Try adding also `-flto` or `-fwhole-program`, and `-Wl,--as-needed`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a virtual destructor is called via a `delete` expression, the `operator delete` that gets called is determined from the scope of the most-derived class.  For example,

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

void destroy_base(Base* b) { delete b; }

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    static void operator delete(void* ptr) {
        std::cout << "Derived::operator delete\n";
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
};

int main() {
    destroy_base( new Derived );
}
```

prints `"Derived::operator delete"`, even though function `destroy_base` has no knowledge of class `Derived`.

g++ implements this by putting two versions of the destructor in every class's vtable: one that just destroys the members and bases, and one that does all that and then calls the appropriate `operator delete`.  This is where your undefined symbols are coming from.

If you never actually use a `delete` expression, just stub out the `::operator delete` function and you should be fine.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the compiler from generating the second destructor? I am not interested in stubbing the delete operator.

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: @GiladNaaman, can't imagine how it would be possible. Standard requires that the proper delete is called, and when compiling the base class, compiler has no idea how it would be used - so it has to generate the destructor which calls operator delete.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I'll write a stub, as suggested.